# MongoDB query for objects in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that consists of objects like this:

```
{
    "name": "Event One",
    "user_id": "1"
    "rsvp": [
        {"id": "1","name":"John Doe","industry":"Software"},
        {"id": "2","name":"John Doe II","industry":"Software"},
    ]

}
```

I am trying to query all events that a user has rsvp too and that he did not create. Then match the rsvp with the industry the are in. Is it possible to query in mongoDB and have it returned like this:

```
[
     {"id": "1","name":"John Doe"},
     {"id": "2","name":"John Doe II"},
]
```

The query I have is below:

```
events.find({"$and":[{"rsvp.contact.indusrty":{"$in":["Software","Information Systems"]}},{"user_id":{"$ne":"5d335704802df000076bad97"}}]},{"projection":{"rsvp.contact.name":true},"typeMap":{"root":"array","document":"array"}})
```

I am new to MONGODB and can't seem to find anything that is helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You need [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to define filtering criteria, [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single document per `rsvp` and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote `rsvp` to root model:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "$and":[
                {
                    "rsvp.industry":{
                        "$in":["Software","Information Systems"]
                    }
                },
                {   "user_id":{"$ne":"5d335704802df000076bad97"}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$rsvp"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$rsvp"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            industry: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AAW9iZi7hjG)

Comment: If I had a user_ id in each of the rsvp records to filter out the current users rsvp I would get add{   "rsvp.user_id":{"$ne":"5d335704802df000076bad97"}} after the other user_id check?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. If you're still experiencing some difficulties please create mongo playground and I will try to take a look

Comment: Need to select all events that the logged in user has rsvp to or has created. then return the rsvp  array of objects like it has

Comment: If you expect to get single document you should re-arrange your pipeline and run `$unwind` before `$match` so that filtering criteria will be applied separately to both `rsvp` items: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hVAKv_6FHLB

Comment: So if this query will get all rsvp that you match industries with including when you created the event?

Comment: @JohnDek yes, it should